# Mesh Lagging Armature

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, blend-files

I modelled a body to learn rigging then rigged the body but my model's fingers are lagging the armature bones in pose mode. When i check in weight paint mode everything seems to be correct to me. To check if i am doing something wrong i modelled a hand separately and rigged it which is working correctly. So i think i have made some mistake while rigging my body and rechecked it and could not find mistake and the side of hand.

Please Do guide me, why my mesh is lagging bones while deforming. Your inputs are highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Here is my blend File:>>>>> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jboPdPqRHOuA3Rfr07e1w2sXshcZARSn/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the N panel if you select one vertex of the pinky, it is also assigned to the *Hand.L* vertex group while it should not:

[image]

If you select the armature, then Shift select the mesh, switch to *Weight Paint* mode and select the bone called *Hand.L* you can see the vertex group called *Hand.L* that will be influenced by the bone. As you can see the fingers are all part of this group when they should not, they should only be part of the fingers vertex groups:

[image]

You can either correct that in *Weight Paint* mode with a brush in *Blend > Subtract* mode, or select all this part in *Edit* mode and in the *Vertex Groups* list, select Hand.L and click on *Remove*:

[image]

Comment: Thank You! Dear @moonboots your reply really helped.

Comment: I think you should mention the Auto Normalize checkbox which could cause weight painted groups to override each other.